# How to get click events of buttons of ContentView page in ContentPage xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, user-controls, xamarin.forms

I have some UI in ContentView page(labels,buttons,editors,entries)
By using UserControl I am getting that UI on my ContentPage, but how to get click events of buttons of ContentView page in ContentPage in xamarin.forms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, you could use the [Messaging Center](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/) to fire off a message when you press a button, but that isn't the most elegant solution.

From what I gather from your question you have made your own user control. In that control define a delegate and an event, like this:

```
public delegate void OnSomeButtonClickedDelegate();

public OnSomeButtonClickedDelegate OnSomeButtonClicked { get; set; }
```

Now when your button *is* clicked we have to fire off this event. Wire up the event first:

```
myButton.Clicked += myButtonClickedEvent;
```

And in the event handler do something like this:

```
private void myButtonClickedEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (OnSomeButtonClicked != null)
       OnSomeButtonClicked();
}
```

You have to check it for `null` first because if no one has subscribed to this event it has no use of firing it. If someone has, then invoke it.

Of course you can supply them with parameters, etc. as you like.

Now in the page where you used your user control you can now implement:

```
myUserControl.OnSomeButtonClicked += onSomeButtonClickedEvent;
```

Comment: Hi Gerald ,
I used your code but I am having errors.
<ctrl:MultiSelect_Que x:Name="MultiCtrl"/> this is my user control which is used in the page but I am error as Error: A method or delegate `Srvy.AddQuestionsPage.onSomeButtonClickedEvent(object, System.EventArgs)' parameters do not match delegate `Srvy.MultiSelect_Que.OnSomeButtonClickedDelegate()' parameters

Comment: Please remove the `object, System.EventArgs` from the parameters (on the line where it gives the error) or ad them in your delegate

Comment: Gerald I have one more question regarding usercontrol. How can I access Controls name used in contentview in content page? This may be silly question but I am new to it.

Comment: Just create a property which returns the name of the control you want. Or if you need more than just the name create a property which allows access to the control itself.